# AngularJs cannot inject ngCookies

Tags: angularjs

I can't inject ngCookies in my AngularJs application?

Error:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Should I link to a angular Libary? Searched for a `cdn AngularJs cookies` but can't find anything.

Comment: Have you added app dependency `angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);`?

Comment: Yes I've got that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ngCookies` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) suggests including the following:

You can download this file from the following places:

- Google CDN
  e.g. `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js`
- Bower
  e.g. `bower install angular-cookies@X.Y.Z`
- code.angularjs.org
  e.g. `//code.angularjs.org/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js`